# Subir archivo a un servidor ftp Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Intentando utilizar el plugin [Laravel-FTP](https://github.com/harishanchu/Laravel-FTP)

**Ajax:**

```
function subir_archivo(archivo){
    console.log(archivo);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'materiales/subir',
        data: {
            archivo: archivo
        },
    }).then(
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alertify.alert('Error',data);
        }, function() {
            console.log('this will run if the deferred generates a progress update');
        }
    );
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function subir(Request $req) {
    try{
        //Direccion local del archivo que queremos subir
        $fileLocal = $req->archivo;

        /*Direccion remota donde queremos subir el archivo
        En este caso seria a la raiz del servidor*/
        $fileRemote = '/';
        $mode = 'FTP_BINARY';
        
        //Hacemos el upload
        FTP::connection()->uploadFile($fileLocal,$fileRemote,$mode);

        return \Response::json(array('archivo' => $fileLocal, 'ruta' => $fileRemote));
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return Response::json(array('Error' => $e));
    }
}
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

> ErrorException in Ftp.php line 46:
>
> ftp_connect() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

**Actualización 1:**

```
?php
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default FTP Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the FTP connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all ftp work.
    |
    */

    'default' => 'conexion',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FTP Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the FTP connections setup for your application.
    |
    */

    'connections' => array(
        'conexion' => array(
            'host'   => 'ftp.xxx.com.ve',//probado y funcional
            'port'  => '',
            'username' => 'xxx.com.ve',//probado y funcional
            'password'   => 'xxx',//probado y funcional
            'passive'   => false,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: No le agregas puerto? La funcion `ftp_connect` espera el  `host` y el `puerto` para hacer la conexion

Comment: tenia un "21" predeterminado, pero sino tengo puerto o no me suministraron un puerto ¿Que coloco?

Comment: Si no me equivoco es el 22

Comment: Ahora no me retorna error pero no lo veo entre los archivos del servidor ftp :-/

Comment: Que te retorna el response?

Comment: modifique la linea del uploadFile y la deje asi: `$result = FTP::connection()->uploadFile($fileLocal,$fileRemote,$mode);` para ver que obtenia esa linea, y retorna `false` pero no indica ningun error, el `try/catch` debería de reflejar el error, ¿no?

Comment: Quizas no es un error y es una respuesta negativa al intentar subir el archivo

Comment: 21 es el puerto de FTP y 22 es el puerto para FTP por SSH (por defecto).

Comment: @sioesi no se q mas hacer :-( el navegador imprime "fakepath" pero realmente ¿la ruta va completa? solo que no la muestra al usuario, supongo, por seguridad como dijiste en la anterior pregunta que hice.

Comment: @Shaz con 22 se cae la conexión por la cantidad de intentos q hace. El 21 solo retorna false sin ningún éxito de subida del archivo :-/